# Find index of list element with maximum value of specific property

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, max, scikit-image

This code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops

image = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2]])
labels = label(image, background=0, connectivity=2)
props = regionprops(labels, image, cache=True)

print(image)
print(np.argmax([p.area for p in props]))
```

will print:

```
[[1 1 0]
 [1 0 0]
 [0 0 2]]
0
```

`0` is an index of `props` element with maximum value of `area` property. Is there a more direct way of computing it without the need for creating a temporary  array in `np.argmax([p.area for p in props])`? It doesn't have to use NumPy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using [`regionprops_table`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops_table)?

```
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops_table

labels = label(image, background=0, connectivity=2)

out = np.argmax(regionprops_table(labels, image, cache=True, properties=['area'])['area'])
```

Output: `0`

Comment: Very nice. I didn't know about `regionprops_table`. BTW, when are the properties actually computed? Does call to `label` compute all possible properties? I'm assuming that calling `regionprops_table` computes only the requested properties.

Comment: I've not checked the code, but I'm quite sure the properties are **not** computed by `label`, only by `regionprops`/`regionprops_table`

Comment: I meant `regionprops` not `label`. I benchmarked it and looked at the source code. `regionprops` does not calculate the property values, only `regionprops_table` or getting the property value does.

Answer (score 1):

Mozway has given you a great solution. I answer here on how to `find index of list element with maximum value of specific property` without creating a temporary array.

A straightforward method is use a `for` loop:

```py
maxid = -1
maxarea = -1
for i, p in enumerate(props):
  if p.area > maxarea:
    maxid, maxarea = i, p.area
```

This can be written in one line using `functools.reduce`.

```py
import functools
maxid, maxarea = functools.reduce(lambda res, i_p: (i_p[0], i_p[1].area) if i_p[1].area > res[1] else res, enumerate(props), (-1, -1))
```